# Sharing a module between multiple modules using forRoot()

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular application where i have multiple modules. I want the following structure

[image]

Where i have common modules which will be imported in a shared module and in the app module only shared module will be imported. The main catch here is that i want a single instance of the services that are present in common module. I am trying

**Module 1**

```
export class CommonModule1 {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: CommonModule1,
            providers: MODULE_PROVIDERS2
        };
    }
}
```

**Module 2**

```
export class CommonModule2 {
        static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
            return {
                ngModule: CommonModule2,
                providers: MODULE_PROVIDERS
            };
        }
    }
```

And in the shared module i am importing these two modules as

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule1.forRoot(), CommonModule2.forRoot()],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: []
})

export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: MODULE_PROVIDERS3
        };
    }
}
```

And in the app module i am doing

```
imports: [SharedModule.forRoot()]
```

and in the child modules of app module

```
imports: [SharedModule]
```

Everything works fine. But i see that new instance of the service from CommonModule1 and CommonModule2 is being created in each of the child module of the app Module. What am i doing wrong . Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: What about if you move the service to `Shared module` or `App module` instead adding it separately in both `Module1` and `Module2`?

Comment: That might workout .. But i want this structure to be there.. i cant change it

Comment: Where are your services located at the moment?

Comment: Some are in CommonModule1  and some in CommonModule2

Comment: Exactly. Now think about it, how do you say you want the same thing across board when they are provided individually in different modules. If the service is supplied to a parent, then the children can gain access to it, else, those 2 services in those modules are like in 2 different worlds.

Comment: Umm yeah ..but isn't that why forRoot() is used for to have a same instance across modules ?

Comment: Okay, I get your point but in your providers array for the different modules, you seem to have 3 different values `(MODULE_PROVIDERS2,MODULE_PROVIDERS,MODULE_PROVIDERS3)`. Isn't it supposed to be the same service so that when `forRoot()` is called in Shared module, it can work as a singleton for it's children?

Comment: Shared module already imports CommonModule1.forRoot(), CommonModule2.forRoot(), which should inturn provide corresponding services in the SharedModule.. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171200/discussion-between-alf-moh-and-vikhyath-maiya).